# How to use UTF-8 encoding in VC++ MFC application

Tags: c++, utf-8, mfc

I'm trying to add **"static text component"** (simple label) with UTF-8 encoding text into my windows application. If I use the designer tool in visual studio 2017 and put the text through properties - everything looks just fine - after opening the .rc file, the text is different (bad encoding).

I read that I need to change the encoding of the file to **utf-8 with bom**, but I have nothing like it there... If I change the file encoding to CP1252, the program cannot compile - so I'm using **Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001** now.

```
SetWindowTextA("ěščřžýáíé");
GetDlgItem(IDC_SERIAL_NUMBER_TITLE)->SetWindowTextA("ěščřžýáíé");
```

this code will do this:

[image]

so it does 2 different things in the title and label.

and this code works only for the title & messageboxes

```
CStringA utf8 = CW2A(L"ěščřžýáíé", CP_UTF8);
CStringW utf16 = CA2W(utf8, CP_UTF8);
MessageBoxW(0, utf16, 0, 0);
```

[image]

Why is it so complicated? Is it not possible to normally use utf8 text?
Can anyone help me solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Don't fight the system use UTF-16LE. See also: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190607-00/?p=102569

Comment: You can't use UTF-8 in Win32 ANSI-based APIs unless you are using Windows 10 build 17035+ and have enabled the "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" option in the system settings.  Otherwise, you will have to convert your UTF-8 to ANSI (potential data loss!), or use UTF-16 based APIs instead.

Comment: You have to convert your code to Unicode, it's an easy job. If you don't feel like doing the conversion, then use `::SetWindowTextW(m_hWnd, L"ěščřžýáíé")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, it was very simple.

```
// from:
SetWindowTextA("ěščřžýáíé");

// to
SetWindowTextW(m_hWnd, "ščřžýáí");

// also 
// std::string -> std::stringw
// CString -> CStringW
// etc.
```

and that's it :D

and also [this](http://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190607-00/?p=102569), it was very helpful and good to understand what was going on there!

Comment: Thanks to Barmak Shemirani and Richard Critten!

Answer (score 0):

You have to save your .rc file encoding to Unicode - Codepage 1200